# TYPO3 v7.6 extBase backend module template path not working

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-7.x

I have created extBase extension using extension_builder. Everything is fine but backend module path not working.
- ***constants.txt***

```
module.my_ext {
    view {
        templateRootPath = EXT:my_ext/Resources/Private/Backend/Templates/
        partialRootPath = EXT:my_ext/Resources/Private/Backend/Partials/
        layoutRootPath = EXT:my_ext/Resources/Private/Backend/Layouts/
    }
}
```

-***setup.txt***

```
module.my_ext {
    view {
        templateRootPath = {$module.my_ext.view.templateRootPath}
        partialRootPath = {$module.my_ext.view.partialRootPath}
        layoutRootPath = {$module.my_ext.view.layoutRootPath}
    }
}
```

I have clear:
- Install tool cache 
- BE cache 
- Even removed entire typo3temp folder 
I have included static template in my root template 
But, it still consider FE template view 
Please assist me, where I did mistake or is it core issue?
Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found solution from here [issue#66306](https://forge.typo3.org/issues/66306) Thank you [Henri Nathanson](https://forge.typo3.org/users/40675)

In version v7x

templateRootPath = EXT:my_ext/Resources/Private/Backend/Templates/

will not work, because Extbase does not now about

> templateRootPath

anymore. The default Extbase-Folder-Configuration is used instead. This is the same for

> templateRootPaths

because this is no array value.

So what does work is:

```
module.my_ext {
    view {
        templateRootPaths.0 = {$module.my_ext.view.templateRootPath}
        partialRootPaths.0 = {$module.my_ext.view.partialRootPath}
        layoutRootPaths.0 = {$module.my_ext.view.layoutRootPath}
    }
}
```

Perhaps there is a way to determine, which form of variables the current systems understands and then use such variable.

Answer (score 1):

this is a known bug

https://forge.typo3.org/issues/64539

what should i say else 30 Characters are needed

Comment: Please add relevant data to your answer from that link. That way, your answer will still be valid even if the link changes someday. Link only answers should be either posted as comments or must contain relevant info.

Comment: Hello #Wadim, thank you for trying to help. I got solution from here https://forge.typo3.org/issues/66306

Comment: Hello #NSNoob, thank you for your comment and helps other to improve their answer. You are extremely right that answer should be in detail so other can found solution here instead of jump to that link or possible link will be remove.

Answer (score 1):

I faced same problem.

TypoScript path is correct, the problem was I have added same key in frontend and backend module.

Changed the frontend and backend module key. 
that works for me.

Try to give different key sometimes that works too. :)