# Extend News Administration Backend Module

Tags: typo3, tx-news

I would like to have a custom view of the news listing in the backend module. 
My own extension has custom layouts and partials but TYPO3 doesn't use them.

`setup.txt`

```
module.tx_news {
view {
    templateRootPaths.0 = EXT:news_review/Resources/Private/Templates/
    partialRootPaths.0 = EXT:news_review/Resources/Private/Partials/
    layoutRootPaths.0 = EXT:news_review/Resources/Private/Layouts/
}
```

Here's my file structure:
[file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mz2u8.png)

Versions used:

- TYPO3 7.6.15
- news 5.3.2

Following has been consulted but didn't work for me:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/33775089/7566899 and
https://forge.typo3.org/issues/66306

edit: Fixed the paths (without /Administration/)

Comment: Did you have selected an page where this typoscript is included?

Comment: Yes, the file is included through my template. See: http://imgur.com/a/2Bwtg

Comment: Try to change the `.0` to `.10`.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. I tried that before.

Comment: Okay, but the logic says the higher number overwrite the lowers. So it must be something bigger than 1 to overwrite the default templates. Than you must select an page which have the typoscript included. If both is respected and don't work you should check if the paths and files are correct.  At the first look they seams to be correct.

Comment: What do you mean by "select a page which have the typoscript included". I'm trying to modify the **backend module** "News Administration".

Comment: In the Backend, you have in the middle frame the pages listet. Click here on some page which have the template included. If you have here selected an page without the template the overwrite doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

```
templateRootPaths.0 = EXT:news_review/Resources/Private/Templates/Administration/
```

The news template file paths are appended to this path.

So if `news` includes `Administration/Index.html`, the full path would be

```
EXT:news_review/Resources/Private/Templates/Administration/Administration/Index.html
```

(double `Administration/`)

I don't think you wanted that.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed that... guess what. Still no joy.

Comment: To debug this: Remove the template+partial files from the news extension. Then rendering will fail, telling you at which paths it looked for the files.

Comment: This is what I get:  
`Fatal error: Call to a member function getDocHeaderComponent() on null in /var/www/web1/public/typo3conf/ext/news/Classes/Controller/AdministrationController.php on line 111`